# Kubernetes static ip ingress on a private cloud

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

We are trying to build a Kubernetes node on our Private VMware infrastructure.  I have the cluster up and running and and ingress running, however I can't figure out how to route traffic to the ingress.

We are using Rancher 2.0.7.

**I would like to have the following setup if possible:**

1. DNSMadeEasy.com to handle DNS A Records (DNS to External IP)
2. Firewall we host (External IP to Static Private IP)
3. Kubernetes Ingress (Private IP to Cluster Load balanced Ingress)
4. Load Balanced Ingress (Ingress to Service with multiple instances)

I can figure out the DNS and firewall routing, however I can't figure out how to set a static External IP address on the Ingress Load Balancer.

I can see you can specify a Host name in the Load balancer, however how does this become publicly available?
Could it be because we don;t have an external Load Balancer?
What am I missing on setup of the Ingress/Load balancer?

Thank you in advance, I have spent about two weeks trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be able to set the Ingress Service to `type=LoadBalancer`. With on-prem infrastructure, this either requires you to have an external loadbalancer like an [F5](https://clouddocs.f5.com/products/connectors/k8s-bigip-ctlr/v1.0/).

One option to have this working is to use [MetalLb](https://metallb.universe.tf/)